# find the location of maximum gradient in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the below dataset which represents water temperatures at different depths.

```
depth   temp
0.0     18.613
1.0     18.625
2.0     18.628
3.0     18.617
4.0     18.599
5.0     18.580
6.0     18.559
7.0     18.538
8.0     18.514
9.0     18.478
10.0    18.424
```

I would like to calculate the depth in which the temperature gradient is maximum.
I tried using `dy=(np.diff(Tw))/(np.diff(hw))` to calculate the maximum difference, but in that case I get only the maximum gradient (i.e. dy), but I would need the depth of the maximum gradient.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Will the measurement depths always be evenly spaced, so the depth values can be ignored?

Comment: how about `numpy.argmax` to get the index of the maximum gradient, and use this to get the depth?

Answer (score 3):

Given you store `temp` in a list called `y`, the gradient is computed using the NumPy's `np.gradient(y)`. You can then take the max of the gradient, the corresponding index of which will be `np.argmax(np.abs(np.gradient(y)))`

Using this index, you can get the `depth` which I denote here by a list `x`

```
i_max = np.argmax(np.abs(np.gradient(y)))
print (x[i_max])
```

**Output**

```
0.0
```

You can combine the above ideas in the framework of Data Frames as well. If you plot your `depth` versus gradient, this is how it looks. You can of course use some interpolation to make the curve more smooth and get more accurate  value. Here it is assumed (also the fact from your data) that the spacing is unity. You can also specify a variable spacing or non-unity spacing. More details on how to use them are here : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

[image]

Comment: I am not much familiar with Data Frames. But what I wrote is pretty much complete once you store the data frame values in lists or arrays. You just need `import numpy as np` at the beginning

Comment: Again, you do not take into account that depth and temp are not independent variables.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, one can additionally pass variable spacing of the independent variable `dx` (here `x` being `depth`) as an input to the `gradient` function. Since the data in the question is equally spaced (unity), the current solution is valid I think.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is `scipy` function `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` , but let us try something different

```
df.iloc[(np.sign(df.temp.diff().dropna()).diff().dropna()==-2).nonzero()[0]+1,:]
Out[729]: 
   depth    temp
2    2.0  18.628
```

Update seems your wording make the answer little bit confused , I have update , notice here should be range like 9-10 is the largest .

```
df.loc[[(df.temp.diff().fillna(0)/df.depth.diff()).abs().idxmax()-1],:]
Out[79]: 
   depth    temp
9    9.0  18.478
```

Comment: What if the sample depths are not evenly spaced?

Comment: If depth is not evenly spaced (e.g., delete one row), it returns in some tests an empty  dataframe.

Comment: But also, is row 2 really the maximum gradient? I think it might be the minimum according to the @Bazingaa graph

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you want pandas shift

```
import pandas as pd

df['grad_temp'] = df['temp'] / df['temp'].shift(-1)
df['grad_depth'] = df['depth'] / df['depth'].shift(-1)

df.max() #will give you the max for all columns
```

Note: You will have NaN for the last value

Comment: It seems from the description that depth and temp are not independent variables.

Comment: Thank you @ksooklall, just a little correction that the second line must be `df['grad_depth'] = df['depth'] / df['depth'].shift(-1)`